# Resharper 5.0 slows down VS 2008 after license is added. Especially ASPX pages

Tags: resharper, code-analysis, asp.net

I just purchased a license to ReSharper 5.0 and it has been almost impossible to edit ASPX pages. I read somewhere that I can disable code analysis on a single page with the following command "Ctrl+Shift+Alt+8". But it also hasn't worked.

Is there a way to disable ReSharper Code Analysis on all ASPX pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ReSharper 5.1, it is way better optimized in specific ASP.NET scenarios.